# ListView onItemClick not working

Tags: android, listactivity, onitemclicklistener

I have a ListAdapter that contains a String array.

When I click on any item in the list, I want the application to pass the currently clicked item to another activity and go to another Activity.

I am trying to set the onItemClickListener but without success.

The Activity:

```
package com.nituach.nituach;

import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class NituachActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener, 
OnItemClickListener    {

Button addNewBuisness;
ListView blv;
public static int bname;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final String TAG = NituachActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    addNewBuisness = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAddNewBuisness);
    addNewBuisness.setOnClickListener(NituachActivity.this);
    blv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    Log.d(TAG, "All Variables was created");

    DataBase dbc = new DataBase(NituachActivity.this);
    dbc.open();

    List<String> cs = dbc.getData();

    blv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, cs));

    dbc.close();
    blv.setOnItemClickListener(NituachActivity.this);


}

public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v == addNewBuisness) {
        Intent addnbIntent = new Intent(NituachActivity.this,
                AddNewBuisness.class);
        NituachActivity.this.startActivity(addnbIntent);    
    }           

}

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {


}

}
```

Comment: Maybe addNewBuisness.setClickable(true) could help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `onItemClick()`-method is empty.

The ListView uses an [`OnItemClickListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html), which exports the `onItemClick()`-method. You Activity implements both a "normal" [`OnClickListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html) (which exposes the `onClick()`-method) and the OnItemClickListener. You don't need the `OnClickListener`, just the former one.

It's often more readable to add an anonymous implementation right at the spot:

```
blv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
    // Your Code
  }
});
```

Comment: What is the way to check if the click is on the button and not on the ListView (addNewBuisness)?

Comment: @Dori add an `OnClickListener` to the button and use another instance of `OnClickListener` or use an anonymous implementation like shown in my answer. The Button uses an OnClick listener, while the list uses an On **Item** ClickListener. Those are **not** the same!

Comment: Thanks! And what is the way to pass the clicked value? (which item was pressed)?

Comment: @Dori the third parameter of the `onItemClick()`-method is the position of the item that was clicked. You can use that to get the data from your `ArrayAdapter`. You should store it as a class-level variable.

Answer (score 0):

Declare a static variable in the current activity and set its value to the clicked item when any item is clicked on the List.

```
public static String abc;   

 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {


            abc = cs[arg2];
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, AddNewBusiness.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
```

Comment: Also, remove the onClick() from your code. No need to implement OnClickListener in your activity. Just implement OnItemClickListener and use the function definition I gave in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, might help u...

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
//here arg2 is the position of that item in the listview, which u can use for indexing the  string array, assumes `cs` is ur string array
    Intent addnbIntent = new Intent(NituachActivity.this,
            AddNewBuisness.class);
    addnbIntent.putExtra("value",cs[arg2])
    NituachActivity.this.startActivity(addnbIntent);    

}
```